# Using Cauchy Integration Formula to evaluate $\int_{B_2(0)} \frac{3z}{(z+1)(z+3)} dz$

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to use the Cauchy Integration Formula to calculate the Integral
$\int_{B_2(0)} \frac{3z}{(z+1)(z+3)} dz$

$B_2(0)$ has the parameterization $\gamma(t)=2e^{it} , t \in [0,2 \pi]$

Cauchys Formula:
$f(z)= \frac{1}{2 \pi i}\int_{\partial B} \frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta -z}d \zeta$

Looking at the Integrad $\frac{3z}{(z+1)(z+3)}$, there are 2 singularities, $-1$ and $-3$. As I understood it, the singularity has to be inside $\gamma$ and $f$ needs to be holomorphic inside $\gamma$. So I will use $f(z):=\frac{3z}{z+3}$.

Now the result should be:

$\int_{B_2(0)} \frac{\frac{3z}{(z+3)}}{(z+1)} dz=f(-1) 2 \pi i=-3 \pi i$

My Questions: Is my calculation correct? Does anyone know a website with problems regarding Cauchy Integration Theorem, that also has solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah! That's perfect. Another posibilitie, that is useful in way complicated problems is using the residue theorem. The only singularitie of your function in the interior of your curve is $z=-1$, so $$\int_{B_2(0)} \frac{3z}{(z+1)(z+3)} dz=2\pi i Res(f,-1)=2\pi i\frac{3z}{z+3}_{z=-1}=-3\pi i$$

If you want problems to practice I recommend you that book: A Collection of Problems on Complex Analysis, by L. I. Volkovyskii & G. L. Lunts & I. G. Aramanovich

Answer (score 1):

Wolframalpha does these just fine. You need to substitute, $$dz = \frac{d}{dt}z\ dt$$

and change the limits of integration. Like https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=int_0%5E%282pi%29+3z%2F%28%28z%2B1%29%28z%2B3%29%29+%28d%2Fdt+z%29+dt+with+z%3D2e%5E%28i+t%29